# Can ffmpeg decode G711 audio

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, codec, libavcodec

I am receiving audio data in `RTP` stream. The audio can be either in `G711 A-law` or `u-law` depending on the source. How to decode the audio byte stream using `ffmpeg` api's? Can `ALSA` on Linux directly play the `G711` audio format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libav for sure supports G.711. The associated codec ID are `AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW` and `AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW`. I suggest you start from the example program they provide and modify `audio_decode_example()` in order to use G.711.

avcodec.h: http://libav.org/doxygen/master/avcodec_8h.html
libav example: http://libav.org/doxygen/master/avcodec_8c-example.html